# Can anybody help me about traffic sign recoganation using sift and belgium dataset?

Tags: image-processing, out-of-memory, svm, k-means, sift

I want to recognize traffic signs using sift and bag of words method. And I use Belgium traffic sign dataset and German tsr dataset, but there are too many images.

I extracted sift feature and I computed K-Means over the entire set of SIFTs extracted form the training set. But in this step matlab gives the out of memory because there are 3668271 sift feature over the entire Belgium dataset.

What can I do to prevent the out of memory problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MiniBatch KMeans, but in your case I would simply uniformly sample a subset of SIFT descriptors prior to clustering.

[Vlfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org) has a [demo application](http://www.vlfeat.org/applications/caltech-101-code.html) that does this.